# Commerce File won't let anyone download files

Tags: 7, commerce, files

I've got a website running Drupal 7.32 with Drupal Commerce. I want to let users download files so I've got the Commerce Licence and Commerce File modules installed and I've them working for a while, and then I updated everything to the latest versions and now I can not download any files that have been licensed - even as the administrator. All I get is an access denied page whenever I try to click the download link, but the link does appear in the View for licensed files.

I have checked the permissions and everything there seems correct - and I've also look at the following issue, which is the issue I am having, with no avail: https://www.drupal.org/node/1288156

Does anyone have a solution to this problem or even a work around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you able to download a file manually if you put the url in the address bar?

Comment: @Geoff I forgot to mention that I am using the private file system. I can download the files if I can on the link once I upload them when I create/edit a product though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else runs into this problem, I managed to solve this issue by applying a [patch for the generation of the access token, found here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2302897).

In breif, the patch is needed because the latest update to the File Entity module (which Commerce File utilises) changes the way that access tokens are generated and Commerce File has not yet been updated to account for this.